# align a tag in center of li

Tags: html, css

I have `<a>` tag wrapperd in `<li>`
I have specific width set for `<li>` tag but am not able to center the `<a>` tag within `<li>`.

Here is the js fiddle for the reference. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigid/X923m/)

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add:

`text-align: center`

to your `li` style.

http://jsfiddle.net/X923m/1/

Answer (score 3):

Add text-align:center to your css for the li tag

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#tabs_ul li
{

text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: Thanks to all... I was using jquery tabs and I didn't notice that by default jquery tabs was giving float:left to <a> tag and that was causing problem